# Setting core data value to @ State

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am fetching the user's cached data from coreData

> @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var userData:
> FetchedResults

I have a field

> @State var bio:String = ""

This variable stores the user input into the field, so I cannot just use userData directly to display the cached value for bio.

**How do I initialize bio with the value userData[0].bio?**

Comment: You don't need a state for that, but can use (observe, edit) properties of core-data object directly. See example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453970/12299030.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in `.onAppear()` as the fetch request will have been performed by then and the variable available. There may be other ways, but you did not give enough code to suggest any.

```
.onAppear {
    bio = userData[0].bio      
}
```