# SwiftUI/Combine: Observe NSManagedObject entity

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, combine, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a question regarding how can observe am NSManageObject entity. For example I have this two CoreData entities(`Todo` and `Done`):

[image]

But I want to observe when the done entity has change. Currently I have the following:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published internal var todo:[Todo] = []
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    private let persistanceContainer = PersistanceController.share
    init() {
        self.context = persistanceContainer.container.viewContext
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange)
            .sink { _ in
                print("sink")
            } receiveValue: { _ in
                print("new value")
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is I'm getting a notification every time either entity has change. Any of you knows how I specify a particular entity in this case `Done` entity?

Comment: `NSManageObject` conforms to `ObservableObject` so you can observe fetched data objects directly via `StateObject/ObservedObject` wrappers.

Comment: @Asperi, can you post and example ?

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453970/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi is not helpful it all is different use case